# Crear funciones dentro de views en Django

Tags: python, django, views

Hola quiero hacer un función donde verifique si la variable existe y te redirija si no, el condición es simple ya la hice pero la cosa es que no quiero escribirla def por def.
me explico en códigos, asi es como lo tengo ahora:

```
def main(request):
    try:
        request.user.estudiante
    except:
        return redirect("/profesor/") 
    #esta es la condición que quiero que se ejecute en todos los def de mi views
    ...
    ...

def trabajos(request):
    try:
        request.user.estudiante
    except:
        return redirect("/profesor/") 
    ...
    ...
```

bueno así esta en todos los def pero yo quería algo así como

```
def myFunction(request):
    try:
        request.user.estudiante
    except:
        return redirect("/profesor/") 

def main(request):
    myFunction(request)
    ...
    ...
```

Así si quiero editar la ruta o algo lo hago desde la función y se les incluye a todas.
De la manera que mostré en el código anterior no me da error en la terminal pero cuando tengo que cargar la vista me aparece:
**RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /estudiante/
User has no estudiante.**

A diferencia el 1re código no me sale error y funciona correctamente, tanto la pagina como condición.
¡De ante manos gracias!

si se preguntan porque es porque tengo 2 tipos de usuario que están relacionado 1 a 1, usuario tipo profesor y usuario tipo alumno, y quería que si un usuario se logea y es profesor no pueda entrar a las vistas de estudiante y viceversa

```
class Estudiante(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
     ...

class Profesor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

no estoy seguro si ayuda en algo ese código pero por si acaso conocen algún método mejor

Comment: Necesitas hacer esa validacion en TODAS tus vistas o en ciertas vistas?

Comment: solo en ciertas, o sea tengo que crear la funcion 2 veces, una para los profesores y otra para estudiantes, y en ambas se lo tengo que agregar a todas las vistas de cada uno

Comment: Acabo de publicar mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como necesitas hacer dicha validación para las dos relaciones (`Estudiante` y `Profesor`), diseñe este decorador para tus vistas, que ahorra código y automatiza dicha validación:

```
class RequiredUserAttribute:
    """If the user does not have the specified attribute, it is redirected to the indicated url"""

    def __init__(self, attribute, redirect_to_url, args_dict_to_redirect = {}):
        self.attribute = attribute
        self.redirect_to_url = redirect_to_url
        self.args_dict_to_redirect = args_dict_to_redirect

        assert isinstance(self.args_dict_to_redirect, dict), 'The "args_dict_to_redirect" attribute must be a dictionary'

    def __call__(self, view):

        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if not hasattr(request.user, self.attribute):
                return redirect(self.redirect_to_url, **self.args_dict_to_redirect)
            
            return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
        
        return wrapper
```

El decorador recibe los siguientes parámetros posicionales:

- `attribute`: El atributo que la instancia de usuario debe tener (**cabe recalcar que las relaciones en pocas palabras, son simples atributos**)
- `redirect_to_url`: La URL o el patron de URL al cual redireccionar si la instancia de usuario no posee el atributo especificado
- `args_dict_to_redirect` (no obligatorio): Un diccionario, con los argumentos de palabra clave para la función [`redirect()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) (pensado para pasar argumentos a las URLs)

Un ejemplo de su uso:

```
@RequiredUserAttribute(attribute = 'estudiante', redirect_to_url = '/profesor/')
def view(request):
    ...

@RequiredUserAttribute(attribute = 'profesor', redirect_to_url = 'app_name:view', args_dict_to_redirect = {'id': 1})
def view(request):
    ...
```

También se puede validar varios atributos con el decorador:

```
@RequiredUserAttribute(attribute = 'profesor', redirect_to_url = '...')
@RequiredUserAttribute(attribute = 'estudiante', redirect_to_url = '...')
def viwe(request):
    ...
```

Al igual que se puede usar en conjunto con los decoradores de Django, como el decorador `login_required`, etc.

De esta manera, puedes hacer las validaciones que requieres de manera optima y sin repetir código, ademas de que no te debe dar ningún error. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Había utilizador solo decoradores dentro de los models en def, donde tendría que crear el decorador que me mandaste o que documentación tendría que leer para orientarme mejor?

Comment: Dicho decorador puedes ponerlo en un archivo llamado `decorators.py` dentro de tu app, Django trabaja así con los decoradores, te puedes fijar en el código fuente y en los imports.